# mintinline inside environ

Tags: environments, minted

`\mintinline` inside of an environment created by `\NewEnviron` of `environ` package seems to be strange. There are some unintended blank spaces, after the macros followed by `\`.

[image: result]

What should I do to fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{environ}
\usemintedstyle{manni}

\begin{document}
\NewEnviron{Par}{%
    \BODY%
}

\begin{Par}
    \mintinline{latex}{\usepackage{stackoverflow}\no\space\in\code}
\end{Par}
\end{document}
```

---

add: `\def\c{\mintinline{latex}{\macros\something}} \c` produces the same error. So is it a problem related verbatim-like things?

Comment: Do you really need `environ`? Why don't use `minted` environment?

Comment: @Sigur, I wanted to put some texts and codes (and other things also) inside an environment. Though I have some alternatives like using `\newenvironment` instead, now I am curious about what causes those problems. Moreover, without considering environments, it makes problems within `\def`. So there might be some cases where I should think about another solution...

Comment: It's not possible to use `\mintinline` in the argument to a macro, including environments defined with `\NewEnviron`. It's quite likely that the problem can be solved with a standard environment. Please, write down the specifications.